# Can't get parameters passed to page callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal-7

I created a module in drupal php then i created a select :

```
<select name="form" id="room"> 
  <option value="0" text="" ><?= t('Select a value')?></option> 
  <option value="1" text="admin_service_participant"><?= t('Services participants')?> </option>
  <option value="2" text="admin_service_candidat"><?=t('Services candidats')?></option>
  <option value="3" text="admin_service_nomine"> <?=t('Services nominés')?></option>
  <option value="4" text="admin_service_gagnant"><?=t('Services gagnants')?></option>
</select>

<div id="list"></div>

<script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                    jQuery('#room').change(function () {
                        var numero = jQuery(this).val();
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url :'<?= url("admin/get-admin-statistique/%")?>',
                            data: numero,
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function (datad) {
                                jQuery('#list').html(datad);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert("Erreur de récupération");
                            }
                        })
                    });
                     });
</script>
```

I got 4 template which i one to load with ajax on change, i implemented a hook_menu for this methode with 1 argument:

```
$items['admin/get-admin-statistique/%'] = array(
        'title' => t('Admin Statistiques'),
        'page callback' => 'GetStatistique',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
```

and the methode :

```
 function GetStatistique($numero){

    if($numero==1)
    {
    return theme('admin_service_candidat',array());
    }
    elseif ($numero==2) 
    {
    return theme('admin_service_candidat',array());
    }
    elseif($numero==3)
    {
    return theme('admin_service_nomine',array());
    }
    elseif($numero==4)
    {
    return theme('admin_service_participant',array());
    }

}
```

the probleme is my parametre is null , $numero =0 i don t know why my methode Getstatistique don't get the number

Best regards.

Comment: in .net i always use this : url: '@url.action("XXX", "XXX")',
                            data: { Indice: numero }, a partial view with a controller which have a parametre and the bindding go directly but in php, i don't know how the binding goes i tried data: { 'numero' : numeroval, }, not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this way....

`url:Drupal.settings.basePath + 'admin/get-admin-statistique/'+numero`

and remove `data` from your ajax request.

I think this may be useful for you.

Thanks,

Comment: also had to add     $numero=arg(2);
in my GetStatistique methode.